# Why does electron-positron annihilation could violate the law of conservation?

Tags: photons, electrons, antimatter, magnetic-moment

Why does electron-positron annihilation
violate the law of conservation?

Electron-positron annihilation is followed the law of conservation.

Conservation of electric charge.
Conservation of linear momentum and total energy.
Conservation of angular momentum.
Conservation of total lepton number

But does not conserve of magnetic moment.

Because an electron spin left or spin down, the magnetic moment is N>S.

A positron spin right or spin up, the magnetic moment is N>S.
[image: electron-positron annihilation](Picture)

They violate the law of conservation or not?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to say here, the Feynman diagram you've drawn doesn't show a positron and an electron but two electrons.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Magnetic moment is not a conserved quantity. Why do you think it should be?

Comment: There is no generic “law of conservation”. Conserved quantities are very *rare*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. there is no general "law of conservation", there are individual laws for conservation of energy, conservation of momentum, conservation of angular momentum
2. magnetic moment is defined in the classical not the quantum mechanical regime. There is no radiation of classical fields at the quantum level . Only interaction vertices as the Feynman diagram shows .

$τ=m B$

[where](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment#Definition) $τ$ is the torque acting on the dipole, $B$ is the external magnetic field, and $m$ is the magnetic moment.

There is no B field at the level of feynman diagrams. If needed it will be modeled with virtual photon interaction. There is nothing to conserve similar to the charge carried by the particles shown in the lines in the diagram at the quantum level.